# (-215:Assertion failed) with initUndistortRectifyMap

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting `(-215:Assertion failed)` while using `initUndistortRectifyMap` Python 3 function. Please let me know why I am getting this error as below:

```
map1,map2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cam_m, dist_c, None, None, (2316,3088), cv2.CV_32FC1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /tmp/opencv-20190505-12101-14vk1fh/opencv-4.1.0/modules/calib3d/src/undistort.cpp:232: error: (-215:Assertion failed) A.size() == Size(3,3) && A.size() == R.size() in function 'initUndistortRectifyMap'
```

I have looked at below posts but I am still unable to resolve this issue.

https://answers.opencv.org/question/68575/initundistortrectifymap-assert-error/

Below is my source code where the `cam_m` has two specific points in my image:

```py
cam_m=np.array([[293.278, -817.067, 918.225],[507.324, -573.223, 831.045]])        
dist_c=np.array([3.3037193933075820e-01, -2.0144603430574297e+00, 0, 0, 3.6424949872867396e+00])
map1,map2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cam_m, dist_c, None, None, (2316,3088), cv2.CV_32FC1)
imageRectified = cv2.remap(image, imageRectified,map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);
```

Comment: Having a look at the [initUndistortRectifyMap() documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a), the `cameraMatrix` parameter must be a `3 x 3` matrix, which is not the case for your `cam_m`.

Comment: Thank you HansHirse. Appreciate your input. I have passed only 2 of the pixels (x, y and z) as I want to undistort only those points instead of the entire image. Any suggestions on how I can come up with a 3 x 3 matrix in that case?

Comment: I added [0, 0, 1] as the 3rd row in y camera matrix and that resolved the issue.