# Assertion failed (K.size() == Size(3, 3) && (D.empty() || D.total() == 4)) in initUndistortRectifyMap

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an OpenCV-3.3.1 code that receives fisheye images and the camera_info.

I'm using the `cv::fisheye::undistortImage(input_img, output_img, K, D);` function to undistort my fisheye images. My camera matrix is a 3 by 3 vector of type double, whereas my distortion coefficients vector is a 1 by 5 vector of type double.

When I print out my `K` and `D` variables I get:

```
D = 
-0.0107835 0.0484281 -0.045424 0.00873738 0 

K = 
286.704 0   413.346 
0   286.782 397.179 
0   0   1
```

However the `cv::fisheye::undistortImage` throws the following error:

> [ERROR] [1599838848.368370935]: cv exception:
> /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp:427:
> error: (-215) K.size() == Size(3, 3) && (D.empty() || D.total() == 4)
> in function initUndistortRectifyMap

I went into the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a871f9e4f7d83dc5851f965bdba5cd01bb7527fe/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp#L427) and found out that the condition for this error is:

`CV_Assert(K.size() == Size(3, 3) && (D.empty() || D.total() == 4));`

Then I printed out the following: (Note that `‘class std::vector<double>’ has no member named ‘total’`, this is a specific member for [InputArray](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga353a9de602fe76c709e12074a6f362ba) so I printed out the size of vector `D`.)

```
K.size() = 3
D.empty() = 0
D.size() = 5
```

Based on this the `K.size() == Size(3, 3) && (D.empty() || D.total() == 4)` should be returning a False and the Assertion Error shouldn't be thrown. *What am I missing here?*

From Documentation:

`cv::fisheye::undistortImage(InputArray distorted, OutputArray undistorted, InputArray K, InputArray D, InputArray Knew=cv::noArray(), const Size &new_size=Size())`

P.s. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536111/215assertion-failed-with-initundistortrectifymap) but it doesn't address my question.

Comment: asserts fail when they are false. if it's false then an assert should be thrown.

Comment: @user253751 I see. How do you suggest I solve this problem?

Comment: well you have to make the assertion true